# How to filter @PathParam for xss protection?

Tags: spring, filter, xss

How to filter @PathParam for xss in Spring?

Actually i need to filter this input in case of xss protection:

1. **Query strings (etc. /name/{name})** - this is what i ask for
2. Headers (done - impl of ContainerRequestFilter)
3. Cookies (done - impl of ContainerRequestFilter)
4. Parameters (done - impl of ContainerRequestFilter)
5. Parts (multi-part content)

XSSFilter is done and running, but how to combine it with URL parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i resolved:

```
    ContainerRequestContext request;

    //clean request body
    if(request.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.PUT) || request.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.POST) || request.getMethod().equals(HttpMethod.DELETE)) {
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(request.getEntityStream(), writer, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        request.setEntityStream(IOUtils.toInputStream(stripXSS(writer.toString())));
    }

    //clean request path params
    String cleanRawPath = stripXSS(request.getUriInfo().getRequestUri().getRawPath());

    //clean request query params
    String cleanRawQuery = stripXSS(request.getUriInfo().getRequestUri().getRawQuery());

    //clean headers
    //cleanHeaders(request.getHeaders());
    private void cleanHeaders( MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers )
{
    for( Map.Entry<String, List<String>> header : headers.entrySet() )
    {
        String key = header.getKey();
        List<String> values = header.getValue();

        List<String> cleanValues = new ArrayList<String>();
        for( String value : values ) {
            cleanValues.add( stripXSS( value ) );
        }

        headers.put( key, cleanValues );
    }
}

//clean cookies
//cleanCookies(request.getCookies());
private void cleanCookies( Map<String, Cookie> cookies )
{
    for( Map.Entry<String, Cookie> cookie : cookies.entrySet() )
    {
        String key = cookie.getKey();
        Cookie value = cookie.getValue();
        cookies.put( key, new Cookie(key, stripXSS(value.getValue())));
    }
}
```